# Create default attribute on creation of an entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

There is one requirement to create a default attribute say 'Test' on creation of an entity like we have Owner field common in every entity in CRM 2011. Can you please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The easiest codeless solution is to have a workflow fire on create of your record. The value won't appear straight away but it will always be set.</strike>

There is no supported way to allow automatic creation of a new metadata attribute on an entity, that is triggered by the creation of the entity itself (it is not possible to register a plugin against the creation of an entity). My recommendation is that given the (surely) rare incidence of entity creation, remember to add the custom attribute yourself. This will undoubtedly take you less time than trying to hack an automated workaround.

---

Edit:
I still stand by disuading you to do this in an automated way, however as a trigger point you might consider harnessing the `publish` or `publishall` message as a way to fire a custom plug-in (as per my note below).

Comment: I need to create an attribute on create of new entity, not record.

Comment: Why can you not just create the attribute yourself? Are you really creating that many entities that you need this to be an automated process?

Comment: I suppose you could put a plugin on the create to add the field, but this seems excessive and I'm not sure the time saved would be greater that the development time. I agree with Greg, just don't bother automating this. Especially as crm-online is limited to 200 entities.

Comment: @JamesWood is it even possible to register a plugin against `Entity`? I didn't think it was...?

Comment: I've never tried it, but I dont see why not - you can create entities with web service calls - Ill have a play.

Comment: Neither `Entity` (nor anything like it) is in the list of supported messages/entities in the SDK (\sdk\tools\message-entity support for plug-ins.xlsx) however you might reasonably be able to hook into the Pre-Operation stage of the `Publish` and `PublishAll` messages and check entity metadata there. If the attribute is not present, create it, then proceed with publish.